# circular class dependency within template member

Tags: c++, templates, declaration, circular-dependency

```
#ifndef CLASSB
#define CLASSB

#include "ClassA.h"

namespace name {

class ClassB
{
public:
    static Handle conn();
};

}

#endif
```

-

```
#include "ClassB.h"

Handle name::ClassB::conn()
{
    return getHandle(ClassA::it().str());
}
```

-

```
#ifndef CLASSA
#define CLASSA

#include "ClassB.h"

namespace name {

class ClassA
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    T myFunc(const std::string&)
    {
        auto tmp = ClassB::conn();
    }
};

}
#endif
```

Calling *ClassB::conn()* gives a compiler error which says that the class *ClassB* is not declared. When I forward declare it I get an error message about an incomplete type.

I can't move the template function to my .cpp files as it is a template function. So, how to fix this?

Comment: I don't see a reason you need `#include  "ClassA.h"` in your `ClassB` header file.  move it to your cpp file and give it a shot?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `#include "ClassA.h"` from class `B`'s header and it should work. But there appear to be multiple compilation problems with your code so it's hard to say (missing function `getHandle`, missing `it()`, missing type `Handle` etc).

Comment: Removing the include you mentioned and adding a `#include "Configuration.h"` in the **.cpp** file  of ClassB, it works.